# How to use pixi.js onmouseout event to scale the object from 1.x back to 1

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

As mentioned in the title, I want **onmouseover** event of an object to scale it to 1.2 of its size, and then on **onmouseout** event I want it to scale back to its original size (1). But the **onmouseout** event does not return to its original size. Related code is as follows:

```js
    var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(800, 500, { backgroundColor: 0x1099bb });
    $("#container").append(renderer.view);
    var stage = new PIXI.Container();

    var container = new PIXI.Container();
    stage.addChild(container);
    
    var bunnyArray = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        bunnyArray[i] = new Array();

    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            var rect = new PIXI.Graphics();
            var width = 70;

            rect.lineStyle(1, randomColor());
            rect.interactive = true;
            rect.hitArea = new PIXI.Rectangle(width*i,width*j, width + width * rect.scale.x, width + width * rect.scale.y);
            //rect.position.x =10;
            //rect.position.y = 10;
            rect.position.set(width * i, width * j);
            rect.zIndex = 2;
            rect.drawRect(0, 0, width, width);
            bunnyArray[i][j] = rect;
            container.addChild(bunnyArray[i][j]);

        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < bunnyArray.length; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < bunnyArray[i].length; j++)
        {

            bunnyArray[i][j].on("click", onClick);
            bunnyArray[i][j].on("mouseover", onMouseover);
            bunnyArray[i][j].on("mouseout", onMouseout);
        }

    }

    container.x = 200;
    container.y = 60;

    renderImage();

    function renderImage()
    {
        requestAnimationFrame(renderImage);
        //renderer.render(container);
        renderer.render(container);
        //renderer.render(stage);
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        var bunny1 = thisPointer;
        
        bunny1.rotation += 0.03;
        
        cancelAnimationFrame(request);

    }

    


    function Scale(pointer) {

       
        pointer.scale.x += 0.2;
        pointer.scale.y += 0.2;
        pointer.zIndex = 4;

        return pointer;
    }

    function ScaleDel(requestPointer) {


        //pointer.scale.x -= 0.2;
        //pointer.scale.y -= 0.2;
        if (requestPointer != undefined || requestPointer != null)
        {

            requestPointer.mouseover = null;
        }



    }

    var thisPointer;
    var request;

    function onClick(eventData)
    {
     
        thisPointer = calcuatePos(eventData);



        request = requestAnimationFrame(animate);


        thisPointer.rotation = 0;

    }

    var requestPointer;
    function onMouseover(eventData)
    {

       var thisPointer = calcuatePos(eventData);
        //request = requestAnimationFrame(Scale);
       requestPointer= Scale(thisPointer);
    }

    function onMouseout(eventData)
    {
        ScaleDel(requestPointer);
    }

    //生成随机颜色
    function randomColor() {

        var colorStr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF).toString(16).toUpperCase();

        return "000000".substring(0, 6 - colorStr) + colorStr;

    }

    //判断是否点击了这个东西
    function calcuatePos(eve)
    {
        var x = (eve.data.global.x);
        var y = (eve.data.global.y);


        x =x-   container.x;
        y =y-  container.y;

        var increaseRectScale = 70;

       

        for (var i = 0; i < bunnyArray.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < bunnyArray[i].length; j++) {

                var instance = bunnyArray[i][j];
                //increaseRectScale *= instance.scale.x;
             

                if (instance.position.x <= x && instance.position.x + increaseRectScale >= x && instance.position.y <= y && instance.position.y + increaseRectScale >= y) {
                    //instance.pivot.set(increaseRectScale/2 , increaseRectScale/2 );

                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = randomLink();
                    a.target = '_blank';
                    a.style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
          
                    
                    return instance;
                }
                
            }

        }
    }

    container.updateLayersOrder = function () {
        container.children.sort(function (a, b) {
            a.zIndex = a.zIndex || 0;
            b.zIndex = b.zIndex || 0;
            return b.zIndex - a.zIndex;

        });

    }

    function randomNumber()
    {
        return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
    }

    function randomLink()
    {
        var hyperLink = "";

        var number = randomNumber();

        switch (number)
        {
            case 0:
                hyperLink = "http://www.baidu.com";
                break;
            case 1:
                hyperLink = "http://www.17173.com";
                break;

            case 2:
                hyperLink = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
                break;
            case 3:
                hyperLink = "http://www.163.com";
                break;

            case 4:
                hyperLink = "http://www.5173.com";
                break;

            case 5:
                hyperLink = "http://www.sina.com";
                break;

            case 6:
                hyperLink = "http://www.qq.com";
                break;
            case 7:
                hyperLink = "http://www.hp.com";
                break;

            case 8:
                hyperLink = "http://www.youku.com";
                break;
            case 9:
                hyperLink = "http://www.tudou.com";
                break;

        }
        return hyperLink;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://files.cnblogs.com/files/kmsfan/pixi.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the code you meant to share? It only makes the squares bigger. And the ScaleDel functions does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You used "+=" for scaling up the Rect and, as Goose Ninja noted, you didn't scaled down in the ScaleDel function. If you want a scale factor of 1.2 just set to this scale.

Turns out you don't need the function `calculatePos` for detecting the target object, since PIXI binds the `this` to them in the interactive callbacks - http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixi-js-now-even-better-at-being-interactive/

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOXKEZ. I just changed the onMouseOver and noMouseOut functions and set the hitArea of each object to a local rectangle: `new PIXI.Rectangle(0,0, width,width)`

```
function onMouseover(eventData)
{

   //var thisPointer = calcuatePos(eventData);
    //request = requestAnimationFrame(Scale);
   //requestPointer= Scale(thisPointer);
   this.scale.set(1.2,1.2);
}

function onMouseout(eventData)
{
    //ScaleDel(calcuatePos(eventData));
    this.scale.set(1.0,1.0);
}
```